# The name (variable) does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, loops, do-while

I have a bug in my program that I cannot seem to work out - even after looking at questions on Stack Overflow and Google. My program throws the exception, *"The name (variable) does not exist in the current context."*

```
do {
      Console.WriteLine("");
      Console.WriteLine("Before you begin, chose a battle to join!");
      Console.WriteLine("1. Battle of Copenhagen - 1801");
      Console.WriteLine("2. Battle of Morton's Ford - 1864");
      Console.WriteLine("3. Battle of Schuinshoogte - 1881");
      Console.WriteLine("4. Battle of Kufit - 1885");
      Console.WriteLine("5. Invasion of Normandy - 1944");

      String stringWarOption = Console.ReadLine();
      int warOption = Convert.ToInt32(stringWarOption);

      switch (warOption){
          case 1:
              //continue all code here
              Console.WriteLine("Loading the Battle of Copenhagen - 1801.");
              break;
          case 2:
              Console.WriteLine("This war is locked, however you can read up about it here: ");
              Console.WriteLine("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battles_1801%E2%80%931900");
              break;
          case 3:
              Console.WriteLine("This war is locked, however you can read up about it here: ");
               Console.WriteLine("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battles_1801%E2%80%931900");
              break;
          case 4: 
              Console.WriteLine("This war is locked, however you can read up about it here: ");
              Console.WriteLine("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battles_1801%E2%80%931900");
              break;
          case 5:
              Console.WriteLine("This war is locked, however you can read up about it here: ");
              Console.WriteLine("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_Normandy");
              break;
          default:
              break;
      }
  }
  while (warOption != 1);
```

Comment: Likely it's '"warOption" because you are declaring it inside the do loop then trying to use it outside that loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring `warOption` inside your `do` block, but referencing it outside of your `do` block in your `while` statement:

```
do {
    /* ... */
    int warOption = Convert.ToInt32(stringWarOption);
    /* ... */
} while (warOption != 1);
```

The variable is not defined in that scope. Move the declaration of `warOption` to before your `do` block:

```
int warOption;

do {
    /* ... */
    warOption = Convert.ToInt32(stringWarOption);
    /* ... */
} while (warOption != -1);
```

Comment: That's right! I forgot to add the, "int warOption = 0;" Does it matter if I add the "= 0", because my program has no bugs, and works as intended without it?

Comment: No need to add it. Default value on declaration is `0`.